# Promoting service word choice

Tags: expressions

If I'm a government agency, I have this public service that I'd be happy to see people use it. When promoting this, how do I phrase it properly and formally? i.e. Welcome everyone takes advantage of it (sounds weird to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to say:

"Welcome! This is our new service, and I hope everyone will take advantage of it."

Here, you are underscoring both your support and belief in the service by saying that you "hope" that everyone will use it - i.e. you wish everyone would use it, but you understand if they don't. This way, you can avoid terms that sound a bit more "strong-armed" (i.e. "I'd like everyone to/I'd appreciate it if everyone..."), but preserve excitement and sincerity.